# AJAX delete method adds two route parameters in LARAVEL

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, http-delete

I am using Laravel Delete method with AJAX to delete a question when it deletes it goes to `localhost/upwork_project/questions` which contains all questions when I click on read more button of any question the URL looks like this `localhost/upwork_project/questions/questions/my-question-slug` and error comes 404 not found due to double parameter of `questions/questions` but when I create question or edit it don't add any extra parameter and everything work perfect but when I delete any question it goes to question's index page and do this shit.
My AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(data) {
            if (data == 'question_deleted') {
                window.location.href = './';
            }
            else if (data == 'question_deletion_error') {
                $('.invalid-feedback').fadeIn('fast');
                $('.question_deletion_error').html('Ops! there is an error.')
            }
    },
});
```

and My read more button code is:

```
<a href="questions/{{ $question->question_slug }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Continue Reading</a>
```

Comment: show the code please

Comment: Bro i'm confuesed with the new layout of stack so I have posted code in previous section and it was not in actual body now I have edited have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I have solved this*, there is an error in **AJAX** as:

```
if (data == 'question_deleted') {
    window.location.href = '../questions';
}
```

**Just changed** `window.location.href = './';` **with** `window.location.href = '../questions';`

Answer (score 0):

So you will be surprised what the answer is, you are missing a `/` in your URL.

I assume you have this questions on `/questions` page, so you will need to change this:

```
<a href="questions/{{ $question->question_slug }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Continue Reading</a>
```

to this:

```
<a href="/questions/{{ $question->question_slug }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Continue Reading</a>
```

notice the starting `/` in the url.

Or just remove the questions completely from the href and use the slug only, as it appends to the current location.

Comment: no bro then it goes to URL as : `http://localhost/questions/questions-slug`

Comment: As I have already mentioned this work fine but when I delete a question then it goes to questions index page then there is a heck with the URL.

Comment: I think there is an error in the AJAX as `window.location.href = './';` but its only for going to index of questions.